# Firefox Keyframe animations on hide & show with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, show-hide, css-animations

CSS:

```
body{
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:120%;
}
ul{
  margin-bottom:25px;
}
.thing{
  opacity:0;

  padding:25px;
  background:#e7e7e7;
  -ms-animation: fadeStep 0.5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeStep 0.5s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeStep 0.5s ease forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeStep 0.5s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeStep 0.5s ease forwards;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  width:20%;
}

li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline;
}
a{
  padding:10px;
  background:grey;
  color:#fff;

}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeStep{ 0%{ opacity: 0; } 100%{ opacity: 1;}}
@-moz-keyframes fadeStep{ 0%{ opacity: 0; } 100%{ opacity: 1;}}
@-o-keyframes fadeStep{ 0%{ opacity: 0; } 100%{ opacity: 1;}}
@keyframes fadeStep{ 0%{ opacity: 0; } 100%{ opacity: 1;};
```

For some reason on webkit browsers, the animation will trigger anytime a .hide() or .show() function is triggered with jQuery. But in Firefox, it only seems to run once.

See the jQuery / HTML & here: http://codepen.io/jonboldendesign/pen/LgEaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do Tabs with CSS3 fade animation?

Try to do it with adding and removing CSS class that will animate the content div.

Here is rewrite of your code using adding and removing css class.

http://tinyurl.com/m2p5w8c

Comment: That worked! I don't know why I didn't think of that. It's strange that it wouldn't do it with hide/show on Firefox but I guess if it's sourcing from CSS. Thanks!